# connect to kind cluster from inside and outside

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

Consider this:

There's a linux machine running on azure.

It has apache installed and browing to mymachine.com works, webpage is displayed. All ports are opened in the azure portal "networking settings".

Now there's a k8s kind cluster running on the machine too with a rabbitmq deployment as NodePort service port 32254.

```
kubectl get svc
```

- kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1              443/TCP  3h17m
- ng ClusterIP   10.96.104.61           80/TCP 68m
- rabbitmq         NodePort    10.96.8.15             5672:32740/TCP,15672:32254/TCP,15692:31802/TCP   143m
- rabbitmq-nodes   ClusterIP   None                   4369/TCP,25672/TCP 143m

All good, but I'm unable to access the rabbitmq cluster from outside.

The ip address of the control plane is 172.18.0.3, so this command works:

```
curl http://172.18.0.3:32254
```

But connecting from outside does not work:

```
curl http://mymachine.com:32254
```

So how do we forward from the public-ip of a VM in azure to an internal IP inside the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add the server to balancer then create NAT rule to forward the packet to specific port on your VM.

[manage-port-forwarding-for-backend-pool-with-azure-load-balancer](https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/manage-port-forwarding-for-backend-pool-with-azure-load-balancer/)

Comment: somehow only got it working with the public ip address set to static. but hey it works